# how to make a shape in svg or with figma

Tags: image, svg, shapes

This is the image which I need to create.

[image: 1]

I need to make this image with svg or with figma in png format. the black portion will be transparent. please help me. thanks

Comment: Use an svg editor such as inkscape to draw whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple path.

`M 0 100`
Move to (0, 100) (bottom left)

`H 100`
Horizontal line to bottom right

`V 0`
Vertical line to top right

`A 100 100 0 0 1 0 100`
Semicircular arc of radius 100, clockwise, to (0, 100) (bottom right).

`Z`
Close path

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M 0 100 H 100 V 0 A 100 100 0 0 1 0 100 Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rectangle that is [masked off](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) by a circle.

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="white" />
      <circle r="100" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="white" mask="url(#m1)"/>
</svg>
```